# ajax .load() breaking my slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe, slick.js

I'm having a weird bug where load() is breaking my carousel.

I have a [Slick Slider](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick) with 3 slides. You can click the NEXT button to move to the next slide. You can also click the slide itself and it loads content into the div of a cat and some text using:

```
$('.frame').load(url);
```

The bug is that after you view the loaded content and click BACK, the NEXT button no longer works. Somehow it breaks the nav. I've tried show() and hide() but that doesn't help.

Please see my [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/katiemoons/pen/4592b0f71e898f21c15b0ebdb13f9293?editors=0010)

And this is the [url](http://codepen.io/katiemoons/pen/2a2078ef1b907fa730679c01e010d422?editors=1100) I'm loading into that demo if you find that useful.

Thanks for taking the time to help me :)

Comment: The document you are loading has a script tag whose src is jQuery. This causes jQuery to be loaded a second time into your primary document and the new jQuery overwrites the first one. The overwritten jQuery has no reference to the slick plugin, so calls to the plugin methods throw an Error.

Comment: @76484 Thank you, removing JQuery from the source url fixed the bug! If you post this as an answer I would be happy to mark it solved. I have one more question, If I wanted to have some JQ in my source how could I do that, link both to the same JQ file? Thank you :)

Comment: @76484 Cool I think the loaded url can use the JQ file from the original url, Thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad that works, but it's a bit of an odd solution. It means the cat document has a dependency on jQuery, but doesn't load it. If the cat document doesn't need to be self-sufficient, it makes me think that you should do away with this document all together and move its content to the parent document and just show and hide as necessary.

Comment: @76484 That's a fair point. My plan is to use this like a portfolio, just load images of projects initially and then on click load a real heavily coded project and fade it in seamlessly, so there's no white window while a project loads. like this fork which loads a cat image to another cat image with text. http://s.codepen.io/katiemoons/debug/31a610580332a470e2dce0c89797e8dd

Comment: @76484 Loading all my projects at once would be really code heavy and slow, I'm trying to build a system that can toggle between a carousel slide and a loaded project and back again seamlessly with no white flash. Because I'm crazy. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in a comment to your question, the reason your Slick Slider plugin stops working after you load the other document is because the other document is re-including the jQuery library into your top-level browsing context.

jQuery plugins make themselves accessible by defining a new method and then attaching it to the `jQuery.prototype` (aliased as `jQuery.fn`) object.

When you include the jQuery library into your document via a script tag, you can call `console.log(jQuery.fn);` and you will see an object with all of the convenient methods that make up the jQuery library.

After you have similarly included the [Slick Slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) library, you can again call `console.log(jQuery.fn);` and you can find that it has a method property named `slick`.

The problem is that when you load the document that resides at `url` that document is inserting a fresh `script` tag into your parent document whose `src` is jQuery. This causes a fresh loading of the jQuery library which obliterates your initial instance. If you call `console.log(jQuery.fn.slick);` at this point, you will find that it is `undefined`.

I have never before seen an entire HTML document (as opposed to a snippet of HTML) loaded into a `div` of another document. This is inserting elements into the body of your top-level document that should not be there, like `<head>` and `<body>`. I am actually surprised that this is causing so *few* issues for you.

The way documents are normally nested within other documents is by the use of an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe). The document within the iframe will be its own sandbox, and its styles and scripts will not be in conflict with those in the parent frame.

You could implement an iframe into your project by replacing `$('.frame').load(url);` with something like the following:

```
var $iframe = $('<iframe />', {
    src: url,
    style: 'height:100%; width:100%;'
});
$('.frame').html($iframe);
```